# different conditions in for loop in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, conditional-statements

```
int main(){
    int a=0;
    for(;a<10 && a>4;a++){
        cout << a <<endl;
        
    }

}
```

In this situation, for loop prints nothing. What I actually expect is printing numbers from 5 to 9. Is it necessary to make the condition true to enter the loop? Or is the a++ statement work just if the conditions are true? Because if the a++ statement worked, I guess the numbers would be printed.

Comment: In order to run the loop, the condition needs to be true. Is it true in that implementation?

Comment: Consider the value of `a` the first time through this loop and whether it would allow the loop to continue.

Comment: yes, how often would you assume the program should execute "a++" even if the condition is false?

Comment: @scohe001 Sorry - I misread the condition. Need strong drink!

Comment: Change `int a=0;` to `int a=5;` and your loop can execute..

Comment: `for (init; condition; increment) {/*stuff*/}` is equivalent to `{init; while (condition){/*stuff*/ increment;}}`. Is the behavior clear now?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I remember several questions where my answer was basically that comment with a bit of explanation added, though I don't know a good dupe target.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I too, remember seeing some answer, that was like this. Since I couldn't find it in a quick bit of searching, I gave up, and wrote a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function never enters the for loop because 0 is not in the interval of 4-10

Answer (score 6):

that will never print anything because the condition to execute the loop is never met

```
a<10 && a>4
```

"*do something while a is bigger than 4 and less than 10, and we begin with a = 0....*"

so the loop never begins....